# Set default file browse location VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following VBA code that browses for a file name within MS ACCESS form:

```
Private Sub Command64_Click()
Dim dialog As FileDialog
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String

Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

 With dialog
.AllowMultiSelect = False

.Show
 If (.SelectedItems.Count = 0) Then
 Else
    filePath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    fileName = Right$(filePath, Len(filePath) - InStrRev(filePath, "\"))
    Me.Thumbnail = fileName
 End If
End With
End Sub
```

I'd like to set a default location for where the file browser opens up to.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the InitialFileName property of the FileDialog method.

```
Private Sub Command64_Click()
    Dim dialog As FileDialog
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileName As String

    Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With dialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "C:\yourFolderNameHere\"
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            filePath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
            fileName = Right$(filePath, Len(filePath) - InStrRev(filePath, "\"))
            Me.Thumbnail = fileName
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome.  That is going to make my life so much easier.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Although use of a trailing slash is not required, as the code will also work without the last '\'. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this:

```
Private Sub Command64_Click()
Dim dialog As FileDialog
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String

Dim directory As String
' Set a default location
directory = "C:\"

Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

 With dialog
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.InitialFileName = directory
.Show


If (.SelectedItems.Count = 0) Then
 Else
    filePath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    fileName = Right$(filePath, Len(filePath) - InStrRev(filePath, "\"))
    Me.Thumbnail = fileName
 End If
End With
End Sub
```